# Extract non-extractable private key from OS X Keychain

Tags: binary-analysis, debuggers, file-format, osx, compilers

**I'm trying to extract a non-extractable private key as a `.p12` file from `Keychain Access.app`  or `/usr/bin/security` on Mac OS X 10.9.4.**

---

Basically, it appears that [`security import` has a `-x` option to specify that `private keys are non-extractable after being imported`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109994/non-extractable-private-key-in-keychain-on-os-x).

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/SecurityTool/SecurityTool-55115/keychain_import.c
- http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471.14/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecImportExport.h

As per above, this is implemented by explicitly omitting `CSSM_KEYATTR_EXTRACTABLE` during the import.  Subsequently, when trying to export, the key without such an attribute cannot be exported.

I could find at least two relevant mentions which appear to prevent such keys from being exported (hint: use `fgrep -OR` to avoid following the symbolic links when searching through Apple source code):

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471.14/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecImportExportCrypto.cpp
- http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471.14/libsecurity_pkcs12/lib/pkcs12Crypto.cpp

---

[I've tried keychain_access from github.com/torsten](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140890/non-extractable-private-key-in-keychain-access-app), but it didn't work.

[I've tried using lldb](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64323/export-non-extractable-private-key-from-keychain-on-os-x), `lldb -- security export -t identities -f pkcs12 -o /tmp/mycerts.p12`, to break on [SecWrappedKeys.cpp::impExpWrappedKeyOpenSslExport()](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471.14/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecWrappedKeys.cpp), but that doesn't seem to work, either, with `break impExpWrappedKeyOpenSslExport` giving out an error `invalid command 'breakpoint impExpWrappedKeyOpenSslExport'`.

[I've tried DTrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088786/track-every-system-and-external-library-call-on-an-os-x-app) to trace Cisco AnyConnect, but I'm not familiar enough with DTrace for it to reveal the datastructures.

[I've tried re-compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152504/include-files-not-found-in-apple-open-source-software) the Security and SecurityTool packages, but they all appear to require bootstrapping that does not appear to be in place.

How do I get the private key?

Answer (score 6):

I've arrived at a solution by researching an answer for one of my Keychain subquestions.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109994/non-extractable-private-key-in-keychain-on-os-x.

According to SecItem.h, this **`kSecAttrIsExtractable`** has been introduced with OS X 10.6.

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471.14/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecItem.h

As such, I've tried and succeeded in the following:

- `scp ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` from OS X 10.9 to OS X 10.5
- On OS X 10.5, as per the example from the manual page:

  `security export -k /tmp/login.keychain -t identities -f pkcs12 -o /tmp/mycerts.p12`

  The `security` app will ask you for several passwords:

  1. the new password from the first dialogue is to protect the p12 that's being exported;
  2. the second one is the `login.keychain` password, which normally would be the same as the login password of the user on the original OS X 10.9 from where the keychain file came from.
- `scp /tmp/mycerts.p12` back to OS X 10.9 from 10.5

Answer (score 4):

I found an easier way with [chainbreaker fork](https://github.com/gremwell/chainbreaker). It works with MacOS 10.14 Mojave. See full instructions [here](https://github.com/gremwell/chainbreaker/blob/master/README-keydump.txt).

In my case, I did the following:

```
$ pip2 install hexdump pycrypto pyopenssl
$ git clone https://github.com/gremwell/chainbreaker.git && cd chainbreaker
$ python2 chainbreaker.py -f ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db -p <PASS>
$ openssl x509 -inform DER -in exported/associated/1/*.crt -out secret.crt
$ openssl rsa -inform DER -in exported/associated/1/*.key -out secret.key
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out secret.p12 -inkey secret.key -in secret.crt
```

Then secret.p12 is ready to be imported on another machine.

Comment: You saved my life, respect